# Google Big Query Storage API Inconsistently Returning FastAvro or Pytz for Timezone information

Tags: google-bigquery

I am reading data using the Big Query Storage API in Python (google-cloud-bigquery-storage==0.4.0 and also today checked with 0.5.0).

For the code:

```
result = bq_client.query(sql, project=project).result()
return result.to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqs_client)
```

From some queries, `SELECT`-ing a `TIMESTAMP` column, I get the following Pandas DataFrame dtype:

`datetime64[ns, <fastavro._timezone.UTCTzinfo object at 0x...>]`

where timezone information is stored in a fastavro type

for other tables, I get

`datetime64[ns, UTC]`

with the timezone information stored in `pytz` object.

As far as I can tell (the source tables are beyond my control and I have not been able to replicate with a public dataset), this seems to be arbitrary - e.g. adding a `limit` clause results in the pytz output - although always consistently with the same query.

Is there a way to always get the pytz format back? (The avro TZ is not serialisable, so needs identifying and converting).

Is this something that will revert when a session expires? (24 hours? or is it possible force a session to end?)

(Not sure where the best place for a support request is and appreciate the Big Query Storage API is in Beta, so trying here.)

Edit:
I am currently working around this by doing

```
for col in train_df.select_dtypes('datetimetz'): 
    train_df[col] = train_df[col].dt.tz_convert(pytz.UTC)
```

Comment: Hi, I have some questions related to your inquiry: 1. Could you provide 1 example query where you get the fastavro type and 1 where you get the pytz? 2. Are you 100% positive all the fields you are querying are of type TIMESTAMP in BigQuery? 3. I noticed this post is a bit old, have you tried with newer versions since? 1.19.0 has just been released. Additionally, Beta features are actually Supported (with no SLA’s) by GCP Support so if you are currently in free trial or has a paid support package you can open a support case.

Comment: Hi ch_mike, thank you for commenting!

YES this seems to be fixed in newer versions, I will add a comment below with some code.

It was very hard to recreate, *I think* it eventually, several weeks later, turned out to be related to errors in the data where timestamps where we has a date overflow (for Python, BQ uses 96 bits, datetime uses 64bits) somewhere in several million rows, which is why I couldn't really post an example.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug fixed in newer versions, possibly relating to a date overflow in the query result set.

It looks is a remaining question about handling overflowed timestamps, which are being handled differently depending other values in the dataset (last line of post).

Raw Data:

```
2019-09-01T12:34:56.123456789,2019-09-01T12:34:56.123456789Z
2019-09-02T12:34:56.123456789,3019-09-01T12:34:56.123456789Z
```

The 3019-09-01 date is a deliberate overflow for `numpy datetime64`

Create table:

```
bq mk -t chris.storage_api_test ts0:TIMESTAMP,ts1:TIMESTAMP
bq load chris.storage_api_test dates.csv
```

Script (Python 3.6):

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage
import pandas as pd

bq_client, bqs_client = bigquery.Client(), bigquery_storage.BigQueryStorageClient()
PROJ = '<PROJECT>'
TABLE = 'chris.storage_api_test'

print("BigQuery Version", bigquery.__version__)

print("="*20, "Table", "="*20)

table = bigquery.TableReference.from_string(f'{PROJ}.{TABLE}')
rows = bq_client.list_rows(table)
df = rows.to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqs_client)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

print("="*20, "ts0", "="*20)
query = f"select ts0 from {PROJ}.{TABLE}"
result = bq_client.query(query).result()
df = result.to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqs_client)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

print("="*20, "ts1", "="*20)
query = f"select ts1 from {PROJ}.{TABLE}"
result = bq_client.query(query).result()
df = result.to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqs_client)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

With BigQuery 1.12.1 / BQS 0.4.0

```
Table -> FastAvro 'error' and String column  
ts0 only -> datetime64[ns, pytz.UTC]  
ts1 only -> String



BigQuery Version 1.12.1
==================== Table ====================
ts0    datetime64[ns, <fastavro._timezone.UTCTzinfo o...
ts1                                               object
dtype: object
                               ts0                               ts1
0 2019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00  2019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00
1 2019-09-02 12:34:56.123456+00:00  3019-09-01 12:34:56.123455+00:00
==================== ts0 ====================
ts0    datetime64[ns, UTC]
dtype: object
                               ts0
0 2019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00
1 2019-09-02 12:34:56.123456+00:00
==================== ts1 ====================
ts1    object
dtype: object
                                ts1
0  2019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00
1  3019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00
```

With BigQuery 1.20.0 / BQS 0.7.0

```
Table -> datetime64 (with overflowed timestamp)  
ts0 only -> datetime64[ns, pytz.UTC]  
ts1 only -> String

BigQuery Version 1.20.0
==================== Table ====================
ts0    datetime64[ns, UTC]
ts1    datetime64[ns, UTC]

                               ts0                                 ts1
0 2019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00    2019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00
1 2019-09-02 12:34:56.123456+00:00 1850-07-23 13:25:48.704352768+00:00
==================== ts0 ====================
ts0    datetime64[ns, UTC]

                               ts0
0 2019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00
1 2019-09-02 12:34:56.123456+00:00
==================== ts1 ====================
ts1    object

                                ts1
0  2019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00
1  3019-09-01 12:34:56.123456+00:00
```

One question that remains is when SELECTing an overflowing timestamp in isolation (ts1) I don't get a timestamp  conversion, when it is with another value (in the Table) it is converted into a datetime.

I think, given the difference in binary representation (96  vs 64 bits) this will always be an issue? although consistency might be helpful.

Thank you for reply, sorry this is a long winded answer / description and that this sheds a little light on what feels like a subtle problem?